# MDX openingperiod, closingperiod and sum(measure) return the same value

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, cube

In our cube we want to develop an overview of the amount of goods and their value at the beginning and closing of a month. So I want to use the MDX expressions `openingperiod()` and `closingperiod()`, they should provide these metrics.

In Visual Studio we have the following code (only for `openingperiod()` since `closingperiod()` has the same syntax)

```
(OPENINGPERIOD
(
[Date Booking].[Month].[Month],
[Date Booking].[Month].currentmember
), 
[Measures].[AT Amount])
```

The results for `openingperiod()` and `closingpeiod()` are the same as well as for the measure [AT Amount] = `sum(Amount)`

I expected three different outcomes, as documentations and examples show. However all three outcomes are the same.

Consulted pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/openingperiod-mdx?view=sql-server-2017

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-mdx-level-12-mdx-timedate-series-functions-openingperiod-and-closingperiod-functions

Comment: You should be using the 'Hierarchy' after the Time dimension `[Date Booking].[this should be your hierarchy name]`. Also, as Mike highlights in the answer, the first parameter should be the 'child level' of the second parameter (i.e., if you want the first date of the month, you need to have date and month).

You can edit your query to add the full Time dimension (i.e., `[Date Booking]`) including its levels and hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing your code against the example, I suspect you are trying to use this technique against hierarchy with a single level.

The example was for a multi-level hierarchy Year / Semester / Quarter / Month / Date. In that scenario, when using the Month level to slicer your measure, the CURRENTMEMBER property returns each Month member, which is applied to return first the child member at the Date level (as specified in the 1st parameter of OPENINGPERIOD).

With your code, the CURRENTMEMBER property returns each Month member, which is applied at the Month level, so it will return the same Month member for OPENINGPERIOD or CLOSINGPERIOD (or effectively use the same Month member for SUM).

I would construct a Calendar hierarchy with Date level below a Month level (other levels are optional), then I would edit your code to:

```
(OPENINGPERIOD
(
[Date Booking].[Calendar].[Date],
[Date Booking].[Calendar].currentmember
), 
[Measures].[AT Amount])
```